# Disable buttons and show hourglass over row (htmx)

Tags: javascript, htmx

I use [htmx](//htmx.org) to updated snippets of my page via [html-over-the-wire](https://github.com/guettli/html-over-the-wire)

This works fine:

```
  <table>
    <tr id="offer_2">
     <td>Sun 27.12</td>
     <td>Spinach Lasagna</td>
     <td>5.00€</td>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>
      <button id="2" hx-post="/offer/2/add_offer_to_order" 
         hx-target="#offer_2" hx-swap="outerHTML">+</button>
      <button id="2" hx-post="/offer/2/delete_offer_from_order" 
         hx-target="#offer_2" hx-swap="outerHTML">-</button>
     </td> 
    </tr> 
   </table>
```

....  after the user pushed the `+` or the `-` button, the corresponding row gets updated with a new version from the server.

I would like to give the user some visual feedback:

- the buttons should be disabled during the ajax-call
- there should be a hourglass turning above the row which gets updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hx-indicator attribute to accomplish this:

https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-indicator/

This will add the class 'htmx-request' to the specified element while the htmx request is in flight.

So you would likely do something like this (taking advantage of the "closest" syntax in htmx):

```
<td hx-indicator="closest tr">
    <button id="2" hx-post="/offer/2/add_offer_to_order" 
        -target="#offer_2" hx-swap="outerHTML">+</button>
    <button id="2" hx-post="/offer/2/delete_offer_from_order" 
        hx-target="#offer_2" hx-swap="outerHTML">-</button>
</td>
```

And then create a CSS style for table rows when an htmx request is in flight:

```
tr.htmx-request {
    transition: all 500ms ease-in;
    background-color:red; // for example
}
```

Note that I'm just using a red background as an example here, for dramatic effect. You would certainly want some different styling.

Comment: According to the docs of hx-indicator "The value of this attribute is a CSS query selector of the element or elements to apply the class to.". I think the docs need a hyperlink to the docs of what great things a "css query selector" is able to do in htmx.

Comment: `closest tr` did not work for me, but `#offer_2` did.

Comment: BTW, I found more useful examples here: https://htmx.org/examples/animations/

Comment: sorry about that!  I thought I had implmented the `closest` syntax for `hx-indicator`!

it will be in the next release (htmx 1.1.0)